# From Month Name and year Get date range of that month in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have Month Name And Year from that I want Date Range of that Month.

**Input**

```
@Input=August 2014
```

**Output**

```
@fromDate=08/01/2014(MM/dd/YYYY)
@toDate=08/31/2014
```

Please Help me to do this

Comment: want to display records from that range stored in db

Comment: Ok, what did you try?

Comment: I am just thinking to do like convert Month name to Month Number and from that split record from db i have problem for toDate Variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
DECLARE @SystemDate DateTime, @StartDate DateTime, @EndDate DateTime
declare @monthid int
SELECT @monthid=MONTH(CAST(@Month+ '1 2010' AS datetime)) 

SET @SystemDate = cast(@monthid as varchar(20))+'-'+'1'+ '-'+cast(@year as varchar(20))

SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, -Day(@SystemDate) + 1, @SystemDate)
SELECT @EndDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, @SystemDate))),DATEADD(mm, 1, @SystemDate)),101)
SELECT @StartDate StartDate, @EndDate EndDate
```

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, you can use [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert a string to a date. Use `%M` for a named month and `%Y` for a year:

```
select  str_to_date('August 2014', '%M %Y') dt
-->
2014-08-00
```

Since the first day of a month is always the first, it can be found like:

```
date_format(dt ,'%Y-%m-01')
-->
2014-08-01
```

The [`last_day`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function returns the last day of the month.  I'm passing in the first day, because the `last_day` function doesn't like the `00` day part returned by `str_to_date`:

```
last_day(date_format(dt ,'%Y-%m-01'))
-->
2014-08-31
```

Combine it all:

```
select  date_format(dt ,'%Y-%m-01')
,       last_day(date_format(dt ,'%Y-%m-01'))
from    (
        select  str_to_date('August 2014', '%M %Y') dt
        ) as SubQueryAlias
-->
2014-08-01      2014-08-31
```

Comment: My apologies but I need it in sql

Comment: @fancyPants: Maybe Amol means SQL Server, although the question is tagged MySQL